# Visual Studio crashes after publishing

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012

I have a SharePoint project as a part of Visual Studio solution. When trying to publish a project to create WSP, WSP gets created successfully but VS crashes.

In event log I see the following record:

> Fault bucket , type 0
>   Event Name: CLR20r3
>   Response: Not available
>   Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature:
>   P1: devenv.exe
>   P2: 11.0.61030.0
>   P3: 5270a974
>   P4: Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Internal
>   P5: 11.0.60226.0
>   P6: 512c2d8f
>   P7: 599
>   P8: 1d
>   P9: System.ArgumentNullException
>   P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> These files may be available here:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_devenv.exe_48382b3deb48d11cfbdcc3f8a5eaedf7163c8_fc6a3110_79b1d4c0
>
> Analysis symbol:
>   Rechecking for solution: 0
>   Report Id: c07c04dc-6b5c-11e5-80d6-00155d0c7f66
>   Report Status: 0
>   Hashed bucket:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set Site URL of the project.

So, no matter if you'll never deploy your project, you need to set this project property, otherwise you will end up with VS crashing every time after publish.